# Регулярное выражение на проверку времени

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Какое нужно регулярное выражение чтобы проверить строку на такой формат

```
12:00
24:00
```

Тоесть я хочу проверить является ли строка временем в часах(без минут)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данное регулярное выражение должно помочь вам

```regex
^([01][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$
```

Comment: Она проверяет и минуты тоже

Comment: Вы если тырите ответ `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038769/regex-for-24-hour-time` то хотя бы под условия задачи его подправляйте :) Исправьте `2[0-3]` на `2[0-4]` иначе у Вас `24:00` под условия задачи не попадает.

Comment: В таком случае выражение будет захватывать даже `24:57`, что не совсем логично (понимаю, что условие было только про часы, но все же). Лучше сделать один простой иф для полночи, чем писать слишком длинную регулярку

Comment: Да и раз автору ответ помог, то смысл что-либо менять?